# Find a CFG for $(0 \cup10)^*(1+\epsilon)$

Tags: solution-verification, context-free-grammar

I am looking for an CFG generating the following language: $(0 \cup10)^*(1+\epsilon)$.
First of all I looked which elements are in the language and found the following:
$$(0 \cup 10)^*(1 + \epsilon)=\{\epsilon, 0,1, 0 \dots 0, 0\dots 01,10 \dots 10,10 \dots,101 \}$$
The dots should represent an arbitrary number of $0$ or $10$ i.e.
Now I had the idea to define the following:
$$S \to \epsilon \,\vert \, 0 \,\vert \,1 \,\vert B \,\vert \, C$$
$$B \to 0A$$
$$ A \to 0B \,\vert \, 1$$
$$C \to 10D$$
$$D \to 10C \,\vert \, 1$$
Can this be an option or do I missed something? Are the furthermore an "algorithm" to find such a CFL? Or should I try like I did...
Many thanks for your help!

Comment: You missed at least the fact that your language is regular. Next CFL stands for context-free language and I guess you meant a context-free grammar (CFG). Since your language is regular, there are standard algorithms to find a right-regular grammar for yor language.

Comment: Yes indeed, it should be CFG! Can you maybe give a hint or send me to a site with this algorithm please?